# How to always enable an ArcGIS toolbar?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, toolbar

On ArcMap 9.3.1, is there a way to ensure that a toolbar is always enabled?  In my case, I want the Standard toolbar (the one with new/open/save/print icons) to always be visible.  I'd like the toolbar to be enabled on ArcGIS startup, and to prevent the user from disabling it.

Is there a callback that fires when a toolbar is disabled where I can write code to prevent it from disabling, as well as API calls I can make during ArcMap startup to always enable the toolbar?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you don't want your users to dismiss or uncheck the "Standard" toolbar?  And if they do, you want to automatically put it back?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for.  As well as to make sure the toolbar is enabled on startup, in case it somehow got dismissed.

Answer (score 4):

You can "lock" your ArcMap template customizations. This way users will not be able to change (add/remove) any of the toolbars, menus etc. without entering the password.

If you open and add toolbar to your Normal template (Normal.mxt), it would be permanent and visible to all at all times.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but other toolbars need to be allowed to be added/removed as the user desires.  Nonetheless, I'm curious, how could the Normal template be locked with a password?

Comment: Open ArcMap. Goto Tools > Customize > Options tab -> "Lock Customization"

Comment: If you're comfortable with ArcObject programming, you can use the [ICustomizationFilter](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/?URL=/ArcObjectsOnline/ComponentHelp/esriCore/ICustomizationFilter_Example.htm) to lock selectively.